# Unable to boot Elementary OS on Mac Mini- Freya 32 Bit

Tags: release-freya, boot, usb-drive, dvd, 32-bit

So, I've been trying to install Elementary OS Freya for a while now and realised I needed the 32 Bit version because Mac Minis have a 32 bit limitation for kernels. But when I tried the USB method, the mac mini wouldn't boot into the USB. So I followed the next steps, to use a disc; only thing is, it wouldn't boot with the disc burnt with the iso.

Edit: When trying to use the disc, it would get stuck on a white screen... Had to force reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to boot with this guide 
https://studyblast.wordpress.com/2011/08/14/guide-mac-os-x-lion-how-to-boot-a-linux-live-system-from-a-usb-drive-how-to-update-any-ocz-ssds-firmware/
 Try to look up the file on google - ISO-2-USB EFI-Booter for Mac 0.01 beta - Ubuntu 10.10 Live
Use the 32bit file